# How can I access aws resources in VPC from AWS glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-glue, amazon-vpc

I have a glue job which is hitting an API hosted over an EC2 instance.

The problem is EC2 instance resides within a VPC blocking all public access.

I tried creating an endpoint interface in my VPC but still can't access the REST API.

The host is always unreachable but when I try to access the API from VPC it is working fine.

The security group associated with the EC2 instance is used while creating the VPC Endpoint.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you create a dummy JDBC connection inside the private subnet and try accessing the API with a Glue job attaching this connection?

Comment: I can't access any resource within vpc and is there any reference for creating dummy jdbc connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to AWS Glue console, under connections, create a connection. What is meant by a dummy connection, is just be a non-existent database or resource for example: `jdbc:mysql://some-fake-endpoint-here:3306/mydb`. After this you choose the correct VPC, subnet and security group. Which means a test connection will not work in this context but what it brings is a way to introduce your VPC, Subnet and Security group information to the job. Testing such a connection can be done using a python-shell job or launch an ec2 instance in the same vpc or same subnet and run something like `nc -vz endport port`.

This connection metadata information will facilitate the launching of elastic network interfaces in your account that allow glue DPUs to communicate with your resource at runtime. More on how connections in glue is discussed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-using.html).

Comment: Thanks @Eman, it worked by creating a dummy JDBC connection and associating it with a Glue job. However, it is recommended to have equal or more ip available in your subnet than the DPU required to run the job. This doesn't seems like an actual solution. This can be more considered as a hack to run Glue jobs inside VPC?

Comment: I suppose the hack would be fake connection but ip requirements are applicable for any job that run with a connection. The idea of DPUs and ENIs is simply because each time you request lets say 10 DPUs, you should have enough ips for the duration of that job run. Once the job is complete, unused eni are deleted. It's a best practice to keep at least eight IP addresses in each subnet available for use but if you have many jobs that you intend to run, using jdbc connections, you can either have a big enough subnet or  use different subnets which will mean different connections per job.